# Repacking a tar or tar.gz file into smaller tar/tar.gz files

Tags: tar

I have a tar.gz file which contains a few million files in it. I want to divide the contents without decompressing it due to a cap on the number of files. Is there a way for me to divide a tar/tar.gz file in multiple tar/tar.gz.

if it is not possible, can it be done in python instead?

1st post let me know if I did something wrong.

Edit: I don't want to put it back together. I want to be able to work on each 'splitted' files.

Comment: "without decompressing it due to a cap on the number of files." - you don't want to *decompress* it, or you don't want to *extract* it?

Comment: I don't want to decompress it. as the cap(number of files I am allowed) << files compressed.

Comment: `tar` combines a bunch of files into one big file. `gzip` compresses the big file into a little file. Decompressing the one little file gives you one big file; extracting the one big file gives you a bunch of files.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, not really well versed with the difference of decompress/extract in this context. I don't want to extract the contents of the tar file.

Comment: Try using `arj` archiver, via `apt install arj`.

Answer (score 3):

split is the right tool for it.

To split a file in 10MB chunks

`split -b10m /path/to/file parts`

To put it together

`cat parts* > file`

Comment: I don't want to put it back together I want to be able to work on each 'splitted' files.

Comment: with gnu-tar you can repackage it with
 `tar -c -M -L {NUMBER x 1024 bytes} -f part1.tar large.tar`

Comment: to work with python you can use the included zip lib . have a look here : [link][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371860/python-open-file-from-zip-without-temporary-extracting-it]

Comment: A `.tar.gz` file is not a `.zip` file.  You probably want [python-libarchive-c](https://github.com/Changaco/python-libarchive-c) instead of [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile)

Answer (score 3):

You can split it with `split`, but the individual pieces won't make any sense until put back together. If you want to split it into self-contained archives, you will need to decompress it.

Comment: I want it into a self-contained archives.

Comment: @JoshuaCabanas You're out of luck. You'll need to decompress first.  `tar.gz` are compressed as streams of bytes and the compression smushes everything together. There's no way to get the file boundaries back without decompression.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to split the compressed `tar` archive into pieces without decompression: the compression is applied on top of the 'tar stream' and this stream is treated by a compressor as an opaque binary stream.

Thus, any tool that could produce a set of tar files from your original compressed tar archive will actually decompress it.

The `tar` itself has no mode that takes a `tar archive` as an input and produces another `tar` as an output file apart from `append` and `delete` modes.

As your tar archive is pretty big, you probably don't want to decompress it several times to extract a files portion by portion while creating separate archive for each set of extracted files.

There is a [python tar library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) that probably allows 'in flight' tar file processing (I am not as strong in `python` to verify this myself). So you could develop a python script that would read items from the source archive and then append them to the current output archive until its size reaches a limit of your choice. Then, the script would create the next output archive and proceed further.

Comment: I am actually working with the python library 'tarfile' which does exactly as you said. However, I am trying to process each file in the tar archive and trying splitting it, so that I can run multiple instance of my program.